# python threading Lock release method being called from other thread

Tags: python, locking, mutex, python-multithreading

Initially I was under the impression that with Locks/Mutexes the same thread acquiring the lock should also release the lock to provide mutual exclusion based guarentees.

After reading python threading docs about [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) object's [release](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.release) method I found that :

> Release a lock. This can be called from any thread, not only the thread which has acquired the lock.

Now I am a bit confused, as if let's say thread T1 has acquired the lock and is doing some work, then some other thread T2 can release the lock and enter into critical section while T1 was still doing work and thus breaking the mutual exclusion guarantee.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Whilst releasing the lock from a thread other than where the lock was acquired is possible, it's rarely going to be a good idea precisely because of the potential issue you've identified

Comment: That sounds right, but why would you do that? Your code should be written so that by simple inspection you can tell that any thread will always acquire a lock before entering the critical section and release after exit.

Comment: See threading.RLock instead of threading.Lock.  Here is how the `RLock.release` method is described: "Only call this method when the calling thread owns the lock."

Comment: @PaulCornelius you are correct, it is defined for Rlock and can be seen in cpython implementation here as well https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fda95aa19447fe444ac2670afbf98ec42aca0c6f/Lib/threading.py#L212 but I was concerned about Lock behaviour

Comment: DarkKnight @quamrana from what I have understood till now is that with given threading APIs a lot of things can be done which could get you in trouble and this is a similar instance.

Comment: FYI in my experience, RLock is almost always a better choice than Lock.